# What are the yellow markers in the field tokens on the map, and how do I complete them?

Tags: gemcraft-chasing-shadows

Whenever I complete a field in *GemCraft: Chasing Shadows*, it gets one section filled in with yellow/gold.

[image: GemCraft map]

I assumed these marked completion of the field, but I can't find a way to increase it if that's the case, even by replaying fields over again.  What do these markers represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These markers represent the difficulty you've beaten the level at, at some point you can unlock harder difficulties by playing certain levels.

If you beat a level at glaring difficulty it fills a second element in with orange. Like in the picture below.
[image: glaring]

- [To unlock glaring you have to beat the field K4](http://gemcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Hextile_K)
- [To unlock the third difficulty (Haunting) you have to beat the field T6](http://gemcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Hextile_T)

Comment: Ah, so I just have to unlock harder difficulties.  I thought maybe one was for playing endless or something but that didn't do it either.  Thanks.